# How do I automatically set WooCommerce Product to draft if sold out

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried using the 'Hide if sold out' option in Woocommerce. But I am using a different plugin to display my products (GridFX Masonry Gallery) and it is still showing the sold out products. Is there a way to change the product to draft when the last item has been purchased and is sold out? Is there a snippet to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous answer by [Maha Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35619315/931438) cannot work.

In a theme functions file the `get_stock_quantity()` method doesn't exist unless you call the product data using `wc_get_product`.

Using `set_post_type` will change the actual type of the post, not  it's status, you need to use `wp_update_post` and set the post status.

This is the code I ended up using:

```
/*
* Unpublish products after purchase
*/
function lbb_unpublish_prod($order_id) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $all_products = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($all_products as $product){
        $product_object = wc_get_product($product['product_id']);
            // This will only work if stock management has been enabled
        if( ! $product_object->get_stock_quantity() ) {
            wp_update_post(array(
                'ID' => $product['product_id'],
                'post_status' => 'draft'
                ));
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'lbb_unpublish_prod', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Better way is to set product stock (1 in your case). Select 'Hide out of stock products'. It will hide out of stock products. But if you actually want to hide ordered products then see my code below:

```
//functions.php    

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'your_func', 10, 1 );

    function your_func($order_id) {

        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

        $all_products = $order->get_items();
        foreach ($all_products as $product){
            // This will only work if stock management has been enabled
            if( ! $product->get_stock_quantity() )
                set_post_type ($product['product_id'], 'draft');
        }
    }
```

This will hide all the products added in the cart for order. You can customize this function as you want.

Comment: You need to add a conditional to check if the quantity of the product in the order is 0, your code will set all the products in the order to draft mode even if they have quantity of more than 0

Comment: @AnandShah, you are welcome to edit my code or any better suggestion?

Comment: A more elegant approach would be to check if the plugin offers a filter to modify the products retrieved and use that to filter products that have 0 stock on hand.

Comment: This will not work. You're outside the product loop so the get_stock_quantity() method doesn't exist. You are also changing the post type and not its status so your products are going to disappear from the woo product list (If the code were working).